# How to Change div text to tooltip in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

this is my div

```
<div class="classdiv">11</div>
<div class="classdiv">22</div>
<div class="classdiv">33</div>
<div class="classdiv">44</div>
<div class="classdiv">55</div>
<div class="classdiv">66</div>
```

i need to change this div text to tooltip using **Jquery** , because i can not change it manually , there are so many (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips). So that user cannot see the div's text first .When he hover this , text appear in tool tip .
I know how to make tool tip ,

```
<div class="classdiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="11">11</div>
 $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

> But here the problem is that i cannot add manually
>   data-toggle="tooltip" and title to every classdiv, becuase there are
>   more than 500 div . so i need a solution in jquery , that cab add
>   data-toggle="tooltip" to every classdiv, and convert value to title.

Also how i can change this text to any attribute and assign this value for example
`<div class="classdiv">11</div>` to `<div class="classdiv" val="11" ></div>`
Please help.

Comment: Add this script `$(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
  });` You need also to change your divs and insert a `data-toggle` and `title` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop all divs and set their respective tooltip text from the div text

**TRY THIS DEMO**

```js
// loop each classdiv and add data-toggle and title attributes
$('.classdiv').each(function(ndx, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var text = $elem.text().trim();
    $elem.attr('title', text) // set title attribute
        .text('') // empty the text 
        .data('toggle', 'tooltip') // add data-toggle = tooltip
        .tooltip(); // activate bootstrap tooltip
})
```

```css
.classdiv {
    width: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 45px 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="classdiv">11</div>
<div class="classdiv">22</div>
<div class="classdiv">33</div>
<div class="classdiv">44</div>
<div class="classdiv">55</div>
<div class="classdiv">66</div>
```

Comment: Thank you . This is what i expected .

Answer (score 0):

For changing the text inside `<div class="classdiv">11</div>` to tooltip in bootstrap you need to use

```
data-toggle="tooltip"
```

in your div and place the text inside

```
title="<your text here>"
```

Example:

```
<div class="classdiv" data-toggle="tooltip" title="11"></div>
```

Also using `data-placement="top"` property of bootstrap you can position your tooltip to top/bottom/left/right.
See demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/koyvnzc1/

Hope it helps

Comment: i need to change this div text to tooltip using Jquery , because i can not change it manually

Answer (score 0):

This is just a single line of code. See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/koyvnzc1/1/).

Script to run tooltip:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Change your div into something like below:

```
<div class="classdiv" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Howdy! I'm a fckn tooltip" data-placement="bottom"></div>
```